# "arm[']s['][-]length negotiations"

Tags: hyphens, apostrophe

Which one of the following versions is correct?

- arms-length negotiations;
- arm's-length negotiations;
- arms'-length negotiations;
- arms length negotiations;
- arm's length negotiations;
- arms' length negotiations.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase [[at] arms length](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at+arms+length) *(not on familiar or friendly terms; at a distance)* is almost always used figuratively, so it doesn't really make much difference whether the apostrophe comes before or after **s** (as S.F. points out, if it comes *after*, you're referring to the length of *two or more arms*).

But in practice *at the length of **an** arm* is invariably what we mean, so as [this chart shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20arms%20length,at%20arm%27s%20length&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), we use **arm's**:

[image]

Note that because of how Google NGrams handles apostrophes, the bottom line includes instances with the apostrophe *after* "arms" as well as those with no apostrophe at all. But it still doesn't amount to much.

Answer (score 3):

"At arm's length" is a negotiation meaning to keep your distance (metaphorically speaking).

Literally, it means you come only close enough to be able to reach out and touch the other party, or rather, only close enough to be able to interact. Thus, the distance between you is the length of your arm; if you came any closer, you would be too close, but if you were any further you couldn't reach.

(Aside: In the case of "arm's length negotiations", the point is to maintain a distance from the other party so that no one who looks at the transaction later might think special treatment was given to one side by the other because of a relationship. Both parties must appear (and in fact be) impartial and fair, on equal footing with each other. Think of it as a handshake rather than a hug. Handshakes are professional, even if the two parties are very close. Hugs are always affectionate. For further explanation, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arm%27s_length_principle).)

So since the metaphor deals with reaching distance, you can only be *one* "arm's length" away, not *two* (or more) "arms' length". (Remember that an apostrophe at the end of the word is only used with plural nouns.) If the other party was two (or more) arms' lengths away, you wouldn't be able to reach or interact.

As for the hyphen, it is truly optional and based on personal preference. However, the general rule of thumb I have heard for hyphenating separate words is this: Only join two words with a hyphen if the sentence would otherwise be ambiguous and difficult to understand. So in most cases (if not all), this phrase needn't be hyphenated. (Commentors, please feel free to provide an ambiguous example requiring a hyphen!)

**TL;DR** In summary, in at least *most* circumstances, possibly *all*, the correct way to write this phrase is **arm's length negotiations**.

Answer (score 2):

A few quick searches support the idea that it's usually "arm's" rather than "arms" or "arms'".

In this phrase, "arm's-length" modifies "negotiations".  When a modifier consists of two or more words, it's called a "compound modifier".  Quite often, compound modifiers that come before noun phrases are hyphenated, making the whole phrase easier to read.  In this case in particular, I would hyphenate "arm's-length", giving the full phrase "arm's-length negotiations".

For more details about hyphenating compound modifiers, see Wikipedia's discussion, examples, and exceptions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compounds#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers

Answer (score -2):

*arm's length* is less than half as long as *arms' length.*

(first means one arm, the other means both, stretched to the sides.)

For this reason using "arms length" is not advised - it's ambiguous.

Use the hyphen if you're using the expression as a single compound, like an adjective: *"an arm's-length distance"*. Don't use it when you use it like you'd use a noun, *"the distance was arm's length*.